# Function with derivatives with "fixed" values at $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> If $ \{a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a non-constant sequence of real numbers, is possible to find a function $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{b}(\mathbb{R})$ ( = space of bounded smooth functions) such that and $f^{(n)}(0)=a_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I am struggling with this problem, arisen from my sleepless nights, since a couple of days, but I have no idea of how to prove/disprove it. I only noticed that if I remove the hypothesis of boundedness and I assume $\limsup_{n} \sqrt[n]{a_n / n!}=0$ then $f(x) = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n$ should work, but this doesn't help so much.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $a_n$ diverges too fast then trying to pick a real analytic function will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outline: It can be done. We use ["bump" functions, please see Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) Let $f_0(x)=a_0$ on the interval $(-1/2,1/2)$ and make it decay to identically $0$  beyond $(-1,1)$ by multiplying $a_0$ by a suitable bump function which is $1$ on $(-1/2,1/2)$ and decays to $0$ beyond $(-1,1)$.

Let $f_1(x)=a_1x$ on $(-1/4,1/4)$, and let it decay to $0$ by multiplying $a_1x$ by a bump function which is $1$ on $(-1/4,1/4)$  and decays to identically $0$ beyond $(-1/2,1/2)$. Let $f_2(x)=\frac{a_2x^2}{2!}$ on $(-1/8,1/8)$ and decay to identically $0$ beyond $(-1/4,1/4)$. And so on. Let $f=\sum_0^\infty f_n(x)$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the fact that $a_n$ is non-constant used or needed at all? (Nitpick: I believe there is $a_2$ missing in the definition of $f_2$).

Comment: Thanks, I had left out the coefficient of $x^2/2!$.  Non-constant has nothing to do with it. Constant would be nice, then multiplying by one bump function is enough!